# Sporadic SQL Server error when trying to connect to the database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I will get the error below randomly when I'm running an asp.net application I am working on.  Usually it will happen ever 3 days or so and I am forced to restart my machine to fix it but it's been getting worse and now a reboot dosn't seem to fix anything.  I'm running the application on my machine and doing a lot of debugging.  All interactions with the db are done through linq to sql.  The db is on another server that I am connecting to.  Has anyone run into this before?  Any suggestions?

> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: TCP Provider,
>   error: 0 - No such host is known.)

Comment: Connectivity, are you able to ping that server?

Comment: Agreed, definitely a connectivity problem. If able to ping server, make sure it accepts network connections through the Network Configuration Surface Area or so application and configure it to accept TCP connections.

Comment: It mysteriously started working again.  I'll check to see if I can ping when it pops up again.

Comment: Talked to some coworkers and it sounds like it's an issue that has to do with out DNS servers.  Found a work around for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be DNS, try to use some different DNS addresses. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar before but it was related to a faulty network card that was dropping packets. Have you had any other strange network problems?

In your connection string to the db is the host entered as a hostname or an IP address. If by name try swapping to its IP address instead. This won't solve the underlying problem by may workaround it for you.

*Edit*

Also have a look at this SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428846/strange-intermittent-sql-connection-error-fixes-on-reboot-comes-back-after-3-5). Are you leaving connections open/orphaning them? That would ring true with the disconnect happening at regular time intervals..