# Unable to connect to hosted SQL Server 2008 database via MVC3 .net

Tags: c#, .net, sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I have had this issue for the past couple of weeks and whilst I've learned a lot I still haven't managed to find a solution.

Basically the error I'm getting is:

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)*

Stack trace:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +6351920
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +412
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity) +6366506
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) +180
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) +6366917
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6366793
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +352
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) +831
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) +49
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) +6368598
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +2194
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +89
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +6372110
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +300
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +132
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +3981391
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +10513049
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +44

[ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.]
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection connection) +11121429
   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +239
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +61
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +221
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +442
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +25
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +89
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +21
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +382
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +80
   _2ndBrain.Controllers.BrainController.Index() in c:\users\apis\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\2ndBrain\2ndBrain\Controllers\BrainController.cs:22
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +79
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +264
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +129
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +826266
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +314
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +825488
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +335
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +20
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +54
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +469
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375
```

I am able to connect to this database using SSMS with connection string:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=sql7.hostinguk.net;Integrated Security=False;Database=orchard_chris;User Id=*****;Password=*******;" providerName="SqlServer" />
```

Additionally orchard is able to connect to the database with the same credentials so I dont understand why my custom built app is unable to.

Thanks for any help,
Chris Stevens

Edit:

Still looking for help on this issue. I dont think it's a connection string issue as I can connect to the database via IIS and SSMS.

I also asked my hosting provider what the issue could be and someone got back to me saying:

> Provided the users details you are using are working, the strings you
>   have should be fine. The most common cause of this if the details are
>   correct is that you've not specified a connection string name when
>   setting membership providers, meaning they default to the machine
>   string. Check that any providers you have reference the correct string
>   name.

Im not really sure what this means, could this be the solution?

Edit 2:

In addition I have confirmed 1,2 and 3 below. Im not sure how to check 4 and 5.

- Make sure your server name is correct, e.g., no typo on the name.
- Make sure your instance name is correct and there is actually
     such an instance on your target machine. [Update: Some application
     converts \ to . If you are not sure about your application, please
     try both Server\Instance and Server\Instance in your connection
     string]
- Make sure the server machine is reachable, e.g, DNS can be
  resolve correctly, you are able to ping the server (not always
  true).
- Make sure SQL Browser service is running on the server.
- If firewall is enabled on the server, you need to put
     sqlbrowser.exe and/or UDP port 1434 into exception.

Also I have confirmed the server is configured to allow remote connections.

Comment: Sharing the code that attempts to establish the database connection could be helpful.

Comment: Right now, this looks like it might fit better at serverfault.com.

Comment: Check named-pipe settings of your database server.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. @JoeDay Im not at the stage where my code is even attempting to connect. Im at the initial point where I think mvc3 should populate my database or at least it does on my local environment. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: make sure the remote db server allow connections requests made from behind the proxy, also are u using a proxy to connect to the db server

Comment: @sgud I tried to check the named pipes settings but as I have hosted on a third party server I dont think I can??? Is that right?

Comment: @3nigma I dont think it can be anything like that as project orchard was able to connect, what do you think?

Comment: @chrisstevens hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/9118335/1747930

Comment: @chrisstevens So you are at the stage MVC3 should populate the database but not at the stage the code is attempting to connect.  You don't think connect comes before populate?  The error is "error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server".  How is that not a connection related error?  Are you trying to use named pipes.  Most Intenet servers don't use named pipes as it is not an efficient WAN protocol.

Comment: @sgud I dont think that's the issue. Thanks though

Comment: @Blam I did understand that, my point was that the code that connects to the database (and then populates it) initially is hidden from me or at least I have no idea where it could be found. My hosting provider has confirmed that I am using the correct connection string. I will probe them for more information shortly but any help that could be given now would be great. Im still very new to this so I apologise if my understanding is poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So coming back to this after a while in hope that I might be able to help someone. It turned out I had a rogue DbContext : base("UnicornsDatabase") in my code that I had forgotten about.

In this case the "UnicornsDatabase" connection string either didn't exist or went to a non existent database.

Pretty stupid really. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting a response from the server that the `DbProvider` likes.  Triple-check the server name, username, and password.

Try changing the provider name from

`providerName="SqlServer"`

to

`providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`

Also see if the `ProviderIncompatibleException` has an `InnerException` that might provide more information.

Comment: No change. I had this before but changed it because project orchards settings.txt looked like:

Name: Default
DataProvider: SqlServer
DataConnectionString: Data Source=sql7.hostinguk.net;Initial Catalog=orchard_chris;User Id=*****;Password=********;

Answer (score 0):

Definitely check the InnerException.

Mine was `Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\\dev.XXXXXXXX.com'` - easily fixed

Terrible exception of `The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string` not helpful!

Comment: OK, so how did you fix it?